# Set Canvas and SVG to have fluid widths and heights

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I have a panel that contains two canvases and an SVG file. I set them to inline-block with a width of 33.333333%. They obey these rules and take 33% each of the container.

What they do not do is:

1. Automatically adjust their height to maintain a square shape
2. The SVG is using a `<use>` tag and seems to be in a world of its own.

The end result I want is the two canvases and the SVG to have the same width/height (to be squares) and auto adjust while the window changes size. I am using bootstrap to facilitate this.

http://jsfiddle.net/xqvx9dyq/14/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div id="container">
                <canvas class="chart">
                </canvas>
                <canvas class="chart">
                </canvas>
                <svg class="chart ">
                    <use xlink:href="#test"></use>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9">
    </div>
</div>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="test">
            <title>Layer 1</title>
            <ellipse ry="39" rx="45" id="svg_4" cy="54" cx="50.5" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000" />

        </symbol>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
.chart {
    width: 33.33333333%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: red;
}

#container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Comment: Does `height: auto` work for you on the svg and canvas?

Comment: @somethinghere No, that doesn't do anything

Comment: Sorry, but if you add `height: auto`, your canvasses (canvi?) scale perfectly. They have a default size of 300x150, and if I set your CSS to scale them to `width: 33%; height: auto` they scale perfectly with the width of your page without squashing them. If you want them to be square, give them the preferred `width` and `height`

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or something? Setting the height to auto just doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: Check my answer and its SO snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, with the code you have provided, your `canvas` elements are *not* square to begin with, they are rectangular. 300 by 150 to be precise, or the default size of a canvas that does not have a `width` or `height` defined.

Once you apply `width: 33%; height: auto;` to it, the `canvas` elements start scaling proportionally and this is the effect you want. Now an SVG is slightly harder as Internet Explorer has some really annoying erratic behaviour, but other browsers should treat is similarly as a `canvas`, which is treated just like an `image` element from CSS' point of view.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.chart {
    width: 33.33333333%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: red;
}

#container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="chart" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
<canvas class="chart" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
<svg class="chart" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
  <ellipse ry="39" rx="45" id="svg_4" cy="75" cx="75" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000" />
</svg>
```

I have removed the `use` from your svg and given it a `viewBox` property - that fixes most problematic cases in most browsers. `use` tags don't work the way you are trying to use them, and according to the documentation:

> The use element takes nodes from within the SVG document, and duplicates them somewhere else.

Notice the **from within *the* SVG document**, that's why it goes into it's own `defs` (definitions) tag. Things in definitions can be reaused in an SVG, but only within it's own `svg` tag. Now I'm not overly into `svg`, so if I have it wrong let me know, but that's what I know about it.

Again, you can see that *because* the height is `auto` and the width is defined, the element remains in proportion and scales with the width of your page. I also had to `float` all the elements to the `left`, as otherwise the spacing used to structure your code will be represented as a space, meaning that every element has some whitespace after it. There are other ways around it, but this works (it has drawbacks, though I am not going into those here).

`Use` (MDN): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use